# JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

This has been asked before, but no other answers work or apply to this situation. I have JSON data being sent to the backend, which then sends a reply.

However, it never triggers the success function of the call, although the data goes through to the server and the backend processes succeed. I just cannot seem to find the problem.

My messy function:

```
RegistrationForm.prototype.sendCode = function(url, error) {

    if (accessCode){
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"vouchercode": accessCode}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
          //success case here. never fires
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, err, error){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(accessCode);
        }
      });
 }
```

And the error:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Which is the output of `console.log(err)` in the AJAX error function.

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'json'` then you can simply debug your code by formatting correctly response in `JSON`

Comment: Are you returning the data from the server in json format or not. It will be good if you just post the return data that you returning from the backend

Comment: are you getting any response in network tab of developer tools?

Comment: Post your `Json` Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requests returns some data which is not valid json. The presence of a '<' indicates html or xml. It could be the servers default error page in case of an internal error.

You can inspect the request return data in most browsers. In chrome it is F12 and then the "Network" tab.

Answer (score 0):

[`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is what you *expect* back from the server. You tell jQuery, the server will send JSON, but obviously it sends HTML (`<!DOCTYPE...`), hence the error.

Set `dataType` to `html` or `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the response is in html. So, just remove `dataType: 'json'` and jQuery should parse it as html and it should work fine.

**else follow the below**

If you're really responding with json, then the chances are that it is being formatted into

```
<pre>{json here}</pre>
```

So, remove the `dataType: 'json'` and in the success handler, do the following changes

```
success: function(data){
   var obj = JSON.parse($(data).text());
}
```